# How to convert a static method into an instance method

Tags: java, methods

If I have the following method:

```
public static void flipHorizontal(Picture v){
    int w = v.getWidth();
        int h = v.getHeight();
        int width = w;
        for(int y = 0; y < h; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < w/2; x++){
                Pixel pixelobj = v.getPixel(x, y);
                Pixel bottomPixel = v.getPixel(width - 1 - x, y);
                bottomPixel.setColor(pixelobj.getColor());  
        }
    }       
}
```

How do I create it into an instance method? I know it has something to do with removing the static but where do I go from there?

Comment: Just remove static.. And it is no more static

Comment: Do not be afraid. Remove static and be happy. Any issue after that, explan it to us could help you.

Answer (score 4):

Once you remove the `static` keyword, you need to change the way that the method is being called.

e.g. if you class was called MyClass, and you were previously doing

```
MyClass.flipHorizontal(myPicture);
```

...you then need to call your method from an instance of the enclosing class. e.g.

```
MyClass blah = new MyClass();
blah.flipHorizontal(myPicture);
```

Depending on the whether the enclosing class (or one of its instance variables) is a `Picture`, it may make sense to remove the input parameter of `flipHorizontal` (as it will be able to access these objects already by virtue of no longer being a static method)

Comment: You could add something about potentially changing the method to not need a parameter. Meaning: the point of not having a static method would be to make that parameter a field in the class instead. Which maybe or maybe not would make sense here.

Comment: @GhostCat so what else did he gain by making that an instance method? Just curious.

Comment: @CMR consider "static" to be more of an abnormality in Java. "static" kills polymorphism (there is no way to @ Override static methods in java), thus dramatically reducing your option space to do things the OOP. It also leads to very tight coupling, as you *always* add a direct dependency on the class you are calling the method on statically. All of that leads to designs that are hard to maintain and enhance, and in practice, also harder to test (because the "normal" mocking frameworks dont support mocking static stuff).

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for the explanation, makes sense. It definitely a difficult thing to initially wrap the head around, everything about OOP can be I guess.

Comment: @CMR You are welcome. I guess you find a bit of OOP related content on my profile. Enjoy reading, and feel free to leave an upvote here or there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i think you do not need get a instance for a static method, you can use the static method with the className.staticMethod.
many static method in the utilsClass ,so you just need the className to use the method ,it is much more comfort to use a instance.
if you do not want use the className ,i think you just want to make the method to a normal method ,just  remove the static keyword in the method.
thank you